# Can Kubernetes pods be scaled besides tight coupling to Hana?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, microservices

We have a Kubernetes Cluster with backend services that pull data from an external Hana and send them to Kafka. The import process starts whenever the pod is started and takes around 90 minutes. Because of the tight coupling to Hana we cannot run multiple Pods of these Backend Services. I have the feeling that this could be somehow improved. But I don‘t know how.

What could be the way to go to have multiple pods for the backend services without pulling in the same data three times into Kafka?

Any other thoughts on this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to have containers that perform only one action.

I would consider the following if you want to run the download & push in parallel:

1. A running container which does the download the data.
2. A running container that pushes the data.
3. Shared volume between the two for the data.

Each of these containers would have their own resources and readiness probes.

If the download & push cannot be done in parallel you could have:

1. An init container to download the data
2. A running container to push the data.
3. Shared volume between the two for the data.

Each of these containers would have their own resources and readiness probes.
This would have an extra advantage that if something goes wrong with the push of data, then you don't need to download everything again and the pushing of data will be retried as many times as you want(depending on the readiness probe configuration)

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in K8ns, please go through the documentation.

In a gist, if the import process is moved to init container as a separate routine on success of that the actual services can be started up in multiple instances.

An example pod.yml is given below - it's just an indicative sample to give you idea.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: myapp-pod
labels:
  app: myapp
spec:
   containers:
     - name: myapp-container
     image: busybox:1.28
     command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
     - name: init-myservice
     image: busybox:1.28
     command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat 
   /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; 
    do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
    - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup mydb.$(cat 
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; 
  do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done"]
```

At the end of it, you will have to break up the functionality of importing data into a separate function - post which you can scale horizontally.